# Exchange 2010 and Evolution - Calendar Meetings crash Outlook

Tags: xubuntu, exchange-2010, evolution

Starting to annoy my colleagues by using Evolution, so could really use some advice here!
I'm using Evolution 3.2.3 on Xubuntu 12.04 with both the MAPI and Groupware plugins installed, and all mail aspects work with our domain Exchange 2010 instance. However, whenever I try and use Meetings in the Calendar, it crashes any instance of Outlook on the domain tied to the same calendar event! For example, if I'm invited to a meeting and I send a positive reply, the creator's Outlook instantly dies. Same if I send out an invite to anyone; as soon as it hits their inboxes, Outlook dies. Obviously this is not acceptable, but I don't want to have to switch back to Win7 since our backend system is all Linux. Any advice?